# Vlookup to copy color of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following tables:

```
    A       B     C     D
  1 Bob     1     6     Football
  2 Nate    3     7     Baseball
  3 Silver  3     2     Baseball
  4 Box     7     1     Cycling

A           D
Bob         ?

Nate        ?
```

I can successfully use Vlookup to fill the `?` cells. For example, Vlookup(A8,A$1D$4,4,0).
What I don´t know is to get Vlookup to copy the color too. There should be a solution in VBA. I hope your help.

Comment: Does the color depend on the contents of a cell? If yes, you'd better go with conditional formatting.

Comment: The first table have conditional formatting. The second table isn´t, I  want to copy the exact color like Vlookup does with values.

Comment: I can´t because that example it´s just a simplification of the true tables. The first table is very large with around 100 rows and the second table just uses a small subset of the names and in that way  I can´t use the same conditional formatting.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down. This is actually a very commonly asked question, with no sensible answer 'out there' on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

1. Paste this code into a new module
2. Select the cells you'd like to format by VLOOKUP target
3. Run the macro `formatSelectionByLookup`

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit
' By StackOverflow user LondonRob
' See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba

Public Sub formatSelectionByLookup()
  ' Select the range you'd like to format then
  ' run this macro
  copyLookupFormatting Selection

End Sub

Private Sub copyLookupFormatting(destRange As Range)
  ' Take each cell in destRange and copy the formatting
  ' from the destination cell (either itself or
  ' the vlookup target if the cell is a vlookup)
  Dim destCell As Range
  Dim srcCell As Range

  For Each destCell In destRange
    Set srcCell = getDestCell(destCell)
    copyFormatting destCell, srcCell
  Next destCell

End Sub

Private Sub copyFormatting(destCell As Range, srcCell As Range)
  ' Copy the formatting of srcCell into destCell
  ' This can be extended to include, e.g. borders
  destCell.Font.Color = srcCell.Font.Color
  destCell.Font.Bold = srcCell.Font.Bold
  destCell.Font.Size = srcCell.Font.Size

  destCell.Interior.Color = srcCell.Interior.Color

End Sub

Private Function getDestCell(fromCell As Range) As Range
  ' If fromCell is a vlookup, return the cell
  ' pointed at by the vlookup. Otherwise return the
  ' cell itself.
  Dim srcColNum As Integer
  Dim srcRowNum As Integer
  Dim srcRange As Range
  Dim srcCol As Range

  srcColNum = extractLookupColNum(fromCell)
  Set srcRange = extractDestRange(fromCell)
  Set srcCol = getNthColumn(srcRange, srcColNum)
  srcRowNum = Application.Match(fromCell.Value, srcCol, 0)
  Set getDestCell = srcRange.Cells(srcRowNum, srcColNum)

End Function

Private Function extractDestRange(fromCell As Range) As Range
  ' Get the destination range of a vlookup in the formulat
  ' of fromCell. Returns fromCell itself if no vlookup is
  ' detected.
  Dim fromFormula As String
  Dim startPos As Integer
  Dim endPos As Integer
  Dim destAddr As String

  fromFormula = fromCell.Formula

  If Left(fromFormula, 9) = "=VLOOKUP(" Then
    startPos = InStr(fromFormula, ",") + 1
    endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ",")
    destAddr = Trim(Mid(fromFormula, startPos, endPos - startPos))
  Else
    destAddr = fromCell.Address
  End If
  Set extractDestRange = fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr)

End Function

Private Function extractLookupColNum(fromCell As Range) As Integer
  ' If fromCell contains a vlookup, return the number of the
  ' column requested by the vlookup. Otherwise return 1
  Dim fromFormula As String
  Dim startPos As Integer
  Dim endPos As Integer
  Dim colNumber As String

  fromFormula = fromCell.Formula

  If Left(fromFormula, 9) = "=VLOOKUP(" Then
    startPos = InStr(InStr(fromFormula, ",") + 1, fromFormula, ",") + 1
    endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ",")
    If endPos < startPos Then
      endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ")")
    End If
    colNumber = Trim(Mid(fromFormula, startPos, endPos - startPos))
  Else
    colNumber = 1
  End If

  extractLookupColNum = colNumber

End Function

Private Function getNthColumn(fromRange As Range, n As Integer) As Range
  ' Get the Nth column from fromRange
  Dim startCell As Range
  Dim endCell As Range

  Set startCell = fromRange(1).Offset(0, n - 1)
  Set endCell = startCell.End(xlDown)

  Set getNthColumn = Range(startCell, endCell)

End Function
```

Comment: OP suggested that the cell colors are a result of conditional formatting: those colors are not exposed via the cell's `.Interior.Color` property.

Comment: @NikBurns I *knew* this would be useful to *someone*!

Comment: @LondonRob any ideas how to use the above when the target cell is in another workbook? Set extractDestRange = fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr) fails as the range is not local. confused.com thanks Rob

Comment: Hi Nik. Make a new question, referencing this one with a link. You can do links with [link title] (url) (without a space in between)

Comment: Thanks rob. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999153/excel-vlookup-and-return-entire-cell-including-formatting-from-non-active-work?noredirect=1#comment40717784_25999153

Comment: Awesome effort ... Good job buddy