# Excel Currency Macro

Tags: excel, currency-formatting, vba

I am trying to get numbers in a specific currency from one sheet in the workbook to another sheet. Currently I am pulling data from other sheets to a master sheet using Vlookups but when I vlookup a number in a currency, lets say Euro, it returned the correct number but in USD. Is there a Macro that can format the cell based off what the currency is on another page?

Comment: post your screenshot of both sheets to some sharing site and post a link here. Or, upload your file if possible. Also you can post macro you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might help: [Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba)
It requires you to write a macro but the macro can be called from a formula.