# Excel: Background of cell not recognised

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully a quickie.

I have a bizarre case of a cell having a background colour, but excel not recognising it as such.

Upon right click > format cell, no fill is shown, no rgb value assigned to this cell. but the cell is coloured and it can be copied only with VBA's `.copy` or the Paste Specials `Keep Source Formatting` and `Values & Source Formatting`

I would really like to know whats going on, as well as how to edit Tim's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696025/vba-macro-error-used-with-vlookup?noredirect=1&lq=1) to copy this colour.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it conditional formatting?

Comment: It might have been a long time ago, how would I be able to tell? Besides which its been vba copied onto the sheet i'm working on at the moment, so I don't think it is anymore.

Comment: Select the cell and check the conditional format for this cell?

Comment: Ha, of course! I'm being silly. looks like 4 rules per cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting is not recognized as a background color in VBA.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822801.aspx

Comment: Welcome :) There is a way to undestand what is the background of the conditional formatting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996384/excel-2007-conditional-formatting-how-to-get-cell-color