# "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" error message

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have tried the code suggested in the question linked at the bottom but get an error on the line:

```
Set getNthColumn = Range(startCell, endCell)
```

The error is

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

This code is supposed to set the colour formatting of a range cells whose formula is a VLOOKUP.

All help appreciated.

[Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba)

Comment: This almost assuredly a misalignment of the parent worksheets. You cannot create a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) using cell references from another worksheet. When you rely on cell references created using the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) there are often conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you put the code into a worksheet's code module.

In that case `Range()` resolves to `Worksheet.Range()` of that worksheet. If `startCell` or `endCell` belong to a different sheet you will get an error.

If you put the code in a plain module, as the OP [specifically requested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22154078/11683), `Range()` would then mean `Application.Range()`, and that would properly construct your range.

You can get rid of that ambiguity by explicitly using `Application.Range(startCell, endCell)`.

Comment: As a bandaid (and proof of the bad parentage) I was going to suggest `Set getNthColumn = startCell.Parent.Range(startCell, endCell)`.

Comment: Fantastic - just adding that 'Application.' was all that was required. Thanks.