# Excel vba using vlookup to copy color of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors, vlookup

I am in need of using VLOOKUP to copy the color of a cell (that is not CF).  I tried to follow the vba code that is posted in the thread by LondonRob at
[Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba)
but am having trouble since not proficient in vba.  Vlookup is needed because Names can be in different order.

I have a sample worksheet where the cell colors need to be copied from the 1st tab to the 2nd tab based on a vlookup of name and column numbers.  I set up srcCell and destCell named ranges and copy into a module the posted vba.

1st Tab

Name     Amt1

Kathy    $500 (cell color red)

Mark     $350 (cell color green)

2nd Tab

Name     Amt1     Amt2

Mark     $350     $200  (need $350 in green cell color)

Kathy    $500     $400  (need $500 in red cell color)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Post the code you got! Ideally, it'd be a working Sub or Function with irrelevant parts removed. Now for your question, have you thought about conditional formatting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to understand the solution at: [Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba), you could try this one instead:

It simply uses `Match` to find and copies the cells with values and format by default.

FirstTab:

[image: FirstTab]

SecondTab:

[image: SecondTab]

SecondTab after running the macro:

[image: SecondTab after running the macro]

```
Sub copy_paste_with_format()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim var As Variant

    Dim FirstTab As Worksheet
    Dim SecondTab As Worksheet

    Set FirstTab = Application.Worksheets("FirstTab")
    Set SecondTab = Application.Worksheets("SecondTab")

    For i = 2 To 3
        var = Application.Match(SecondTab.Range("A" & i), FirstTab.Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(var) Then
            FirstTab.Range("B" & var).Copy SecondTab.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```