# Excel macro vlookup with formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, vlookup

I found this code through Google and I'm trying to get it to work for me. 
[Vlookup to copy color of a cell - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba)

I have an Excel workbook in which I want to easily `VLOOKUP` values and formatting from an Excel sheet I did the week before.

I can download a list from our database with pricing. 
Then manually a from/to price is added in the cells. This happens every week. I have to copy paste it manually every week because the `VLOOKUP` doesn't add the formatting.

Here is source (oud) looks:
[image]

My `VLOOKUP` returns the values correctly, I just want the formatting as well.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;oud!A:D;4;FALSE)
```

I cant get the earlier mentioned macro on the link to work. I'm fairly new to VBA so treat me as a newby ;)

Anybody can help? It would save me a lot of time every week :)

```
Option Explicit
' By StackOverflow user LondonRob
' See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell-excel-vba

Public Sub formatSelectionByLookup()
  ' Select the range you'd like to format then
  ' run this macro
  copyLookupFormatting Selection

End Sub

Private Sub copyLookupFormatting(destRange As Range)
  ' Take each cell in destRange and copy the formatting
  ' from the destination cell (either itself or
  ' the vlookup target if the cell is a vlookup)
  Dim destCell As Range
  Dim srcCell As Range

  For Each destCell In destRange
    Set srcCell = getDestCell(destCell)
    copyFormatting destCell, srcCell
  Next destCell

End Sub

Private Sub copyFormatting(destCell As Range, srcCell As Range)
  ' Copy the formatting of srcCell into destCell
  ' This can be extended to include, e.g. borders
  destCell.Font.Color = srcCell.Font.Color
  destCell.Font.Bold = srcCell.Font.Bold
  destCell.Font.Size = srcCell.Font.Size

  destCell.Interior.Color = srcCell.Interior.Color

End Sub

Private Function getDestCell(fromCell As Range) As Range
  ' If fromCell is a vlookup, return the cell
  ' pointed at by the vlookup. Otherwise return the
  ' cell itself.
  Dim srcColNum As Integer
  Dim srcRowNum As Integer
  Dim srcRange As Range
  Dim srcCol As Range

  srcColNum = extractLookupColNum(fromCell)
  Set srcRange = extractDestRange(fromCell)
  Set srcCol = getNthColumn(srcRange, srcColNum)
  srcRowNum = Application.Match(fromCell.Value, srcCol, 0)
  Set getDestCell = srcRange.Cells(srcRowNum, srcColNum)

End Function

Private Function extractDestRange(fromCell As Range) As Range
  ' Get the destination range of a vlookup in the formulat
  ' of fromCell. Returns fromCell itself if no vlookup is
  ' detected.
  Dim fromFormula As String
  Dim startPos As Integer
  Dim endPos As Integer
  Dim destAddr As String

  fromFormula = fromCell.Formula

  If Left(fromFormula, 9) = "=VLOOKUP(" Then
    startPos = InStr(fromFormula, ",") + 1
    endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ",")
    destAddr = Trim(Mid(fromFormula, startPos, endPos - startPos))
  Else
    destAddr = fromCell.Address
  End If
  Set extractDestRange = fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr)

End Function

Private Function extractLookupColNum(fromCell As Range) As Integer
  ' If fromCell contains a vlookup, return the number of the
  ' column requested by the vlookup. Otherwise return 1
  Dim fromFormula As String
  Dim startPos As Integer
  Dim endPos As Integer
  Dim colNumber As String

  fromFormula = fromCell.Formula

  If Left(fromFormula, 9) = "=VLOOKUP(" Then
    startPos = InStr(InStr(fromFormula, ",") + 1, fromFormula, ",") + 1
    endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ",")
    If endPos < startPos Then
      endPos = InStr(startPos, fromFormula, ")")
    End If
    colNumber = Trim(Mid(fromFormula, startPos, endPos - startPos))
  Else
    colNumber = 1
  End If

  extractLookupColNum = colNumber

End Function

Private Function getNthColumn(fromRange As Range, n As Integer) As Range
  ' Get the Nth column from fromRange
  Dim startCell As Range
  Dim endCell As Range

  Set startCell = fromRange(1).Offset(0, n - 1)
  Set endCell = startCell.End(xlDown)

  Set getNthColumn = Range(startCell, endCell)

End Function
```

I copied the code pasted into a macro sheet. Added a button in my workbook that linked to the macro. Selected the range of the net price column where I have the vlookup. Then I press the button and get this error that leads to:

```
Set extractDestRange = fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr)
```

> run-time error '1004': application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Please add the code into your question ([edit]) you are actually using and then tell which error you get and where. And what the difference between the actual behavior and the desired behavior is, because *"can't get it to work"* is no useful error description.

Comment: Ok sorry! I copied the code on the above mentioned URL, pasted into a macro sheet. Added a button in my workbook that linked to the macro. Selected the range of the net price column where I have the vlookup. Then I press the button and get this error that leads to:   Set extractDestRange = fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr)       run-time error '1004': application-defined or object defined error

Comment: I think you misunderstood @pᴇʜ - please put the copied code in your question here.

Comment: I think for your case a function to do a simple loop and copy would be a better choice.