# Vlookup from other files and with keeping formats

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have 33 files with different company departments in which we keep working hours of our staff. In each of them there's few people working there.

I write a "master" excel which keeps all the data from those 33 different files.
I've managed to write couple of formulas to keep it loading data properly. But I've got only values correcly.

Still I need to load cell colors which are crucial to us. Do you have any ideas how to achive that? I've already looked at [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151426/vlookup-to-copy-color-of-a-cell) but I can't keep it working.
Was thinkg also about merging files with VBA but without any luck - I still end up only with values, not colors of cells.

[image: Just a sample what I'm doing]

Comment: You should post your code so we can see how you are transferring values. You can copy/paste or store the colours separately, e.g. in an array.

Comment: did you check conditional formating? I think it will help you [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f]

Comment: Formulas don't transfer formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this UDF to get cell color and formats

Copy below code Module1,

Use LookupFormat as a formula
=LookupFormat(A1,Sheet2!A1:D100,4)
This will fetch Value as well as cell format

```
Public IntClr, IntShade, FntClr, FntShade, CellAdd
Function LookupFormat(ByRef FndValue, ByRef LookupRng As Range, ByRef ColRef As Long)
    Set FindCell = LookupRng.Find(What:=FndValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    CellAdd = Application.Caller.Address
    With FindCell
        FindRow = .Row
        FindCol = .Column
        With .Offset(0, ColRef - 1)
            With .Interior
                IntClr = .Color
                IntShade = .TintAndShade
            End With
            With .Font
                FntClr = .Color
                FntShade = .TintAndShade
            End With
            LookupFormat = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Copy below macro to WorkSheet Module

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If CellAdd = "" Then Exit Sub
    RefChk = IntClr & IntShade & FntClr & FntShade
    If RefChk = "" Then Exit Sub
    With Range(CellAdd)
        With .Interior
            .Color = IntClr
            .TintAndShade = IntShade
        End With
        With .Font
            .Color = FntClr
            .TintAndShade = FntShade
        End With
    End With
    IntClr = ""
    IntShade = ""
    FntClr = ""
    FntShade = ""
    CellAdd = ""
End Sub
```

ref: https://quadexcel.com/wp/vlookup-get-cell-color-font-color-along-lookup-value/

Edit: updated with how to use that UDF, thanks Tim

Comment: "UDF" usually refers to a function called from a worksheet cell - this will not work in that context, since a UDF can't update a worksheet directly.